# Would this breach copyright on Dr Who?

Tags: copyright

If I write a story about an alien time traveller from a dying race, with encyclopedic knowledge, who sporadically visits London, travels with young companions, occasionally saves Earth and other planets, and appears to change bodies periodically. Would this be a breach of copyright?

Answer (score 2):

There is too little detail in your question to give a clear answer. In fact, to get an authoritative answer, you need to let a IP lawyer read the full story and give a legal opinion.

The answer depends on how you write the story.

Copyright gives the copyright holder control over [*derivative works*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work), so if your story can be classified as a derivative work of Dr. Who, and is not covered by the *exceptions* that exist in copyright law (i.e. Parody, Fair use), then you would breach copyright.

However, if your story just happens to use a similar story framework as Dr. Who, but where the plotlines, settings and and personality of main characters are all different from Dr. Who, then it probably will not be considered a derivative work and you would be OK.